# How to get value of XML element using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, value-of

I have a XML and XSL code, products have images and description. I want to append this images in description tag.

```
<images>
  <img_item type_name="">http://www.example.com.tr/ExampleData/example1.jpg</img_item>
  <img_item type_name="">http://www.example.com.tr/ExampleData/example2.jpg</img_item>
  <img_item type_name="">http://www.example.com.tr/ExampleData/example3.jpg</img_item>
</images>
```

I write XSL code like this (But it does not get value of img_type) :

```
      <Description>
        <xsl:for-each select="images/img_item">
          <xsl:text><![CDATA[<br/><img src="]]></xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="images/img_item"/>
          <xsl:text><![CDATA[" />]]></xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Description>
```

My Code does not work. How can i get value of img_type (how can i get these links.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not getting and value is because are already positioned on the `img_item`, and your `xsl:value-of` select will be relative to that. So you just need to do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

Howver, you should avoid using CDATA to write out tags (unless you genuinely do want them to be escaped). Just write out the element you want directly

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <Description>
    <xsl:for-each select="images/img_item">
      <br />
      <img src="{.}" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Description>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to write out the `src` attribute value.